# strictly increasing concave function on R+

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

the real analysis book says that 
$$f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$$ where $f$ is strictly increasing and concave function. it has the following property
$$f(ax+(1-a)y) \le f(ax) + f((1-a)y)$$
where $a \in [0,1]$.

This property seems wrong. As far as I know, that property is for convex function, not concave function. I do not think the textbook is wrong. Can you please explain it?

The textbook used it to show the function $d(x,y)$ is a matric in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You are correct.  The inequality is wrong.  $f(ax+(1-a)y\ge af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Definition

Comment: I think it should be($<$ ) if function is strictly increasing and $a\in \left( 0,1 \right) $

Comment: It doesn't matter if $f$ is increasing or not. The defining property of a concave functions is $f(ax+(1-a)y)\ge af(x) + (1-a)f(y).$

Comment: That property is not generally a property of either convex or concave function in general. Convex functions do not generally have the property above either (its closer to a property that a concave function will have); due to the scope of $a$ being within $F$, on the RHS of the equation). unless they are sub-additive as well, such as sub-linear models. However, the question did specify some additional requirements, not just ask, the reader, to prove or define the definition of concavity.

Comment: Perhaps if one can show that $F(tx)\, \geq\, tF(x)$ using continuity, using the positive range and domain, and strict monotonicity.... I am not sure what the conditions are for sub-additivity of a concave function when $0$ is not an element of the domain. Whether positivity, or non-negaitivity and strict monotone increasing suffice. I feel that is its going to be approximately correct, given continuity. As there will be some element, of the domain $y= \epsilon $ almost equal to $0$, st $F(tx)~=F(tx +1-t \epsilon) \geq tF(x)+(1-t)F(\epsilon)> tF(x) \rightarrow  F(tx)\geq tF(x)$ arguably

Comment: It is probably a typo in the book.

Comment: For $f = \ln$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = y = 1$ we have $$f( a x + (1 - a) y) = \ln(1) = 0 > - \ln(4) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1\right) + \ln\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1\right) = f(a x)  +f((1-a) y),$$ so the inequality does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

hmmmmm. I am not sure. The property you mention is not generally a property (in general) of either concave or convex functions, but actually of sub-additive functions. However, I am inclined to believe that the conjecture, or the book may be correct for the following reasoning.

Technically,  (on the average, to abuse terminology) a property that would most likely be shared by concave functions over the positive reals, rather then convex functions. Unless its one of these sub-linear or super-linear functions which are some admixture of both (and almost, both,'convex and concave', or super-additive, and sub-additive) over $[0,1]$)

Notice that in $(1)$ the scope of the multiplicative elements $a$ and $(1-a)$ is within $F$ not outside $F$ as in $(2)$ and $(3)$. If one can show that $F$ is sub-additive or that F(tx)>=tF(x) it should be.

$(1)f(ax+(1−a)y)≤f(ax)+f((1−a)y)$

Convex: $f(ax+(1−a)y) ≤a f(x)+(1−a)f(y)$

Concave:  $f(ax+(1−a)y)\geq af(x)+(1−a)f(y)$

I agree that $(1)$ definitely **Seems** wrong for concave $F$ but it actually may not be.  Remember that  the  "above" $(1)$ is a property that function, $F$ 'sub-additive over the positive reals' may have.

Concave functions are  sub-additive,  over the **positive reals**, when $f(0) ≥ 0$,see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function. See pt 10.
Although the domain only specifies positive- reals, not-non-negative reals and may not  include the $0$. That is the only the issue. It also not a closed domain and range either.

However, given the positive domain,  and strict monotonic increasing-ness, it might have the same effect, and the conjecture MIGHT (I stress) be correct. It will also be strictly quasi convex and strictly quasi concave.

If $F$ is concave and,$f(0) ≥ 0$ then $F$  is sub-additive over the positive reals; so the book, is "arguably" correct.

I  (stress) arguably, as the  the domain, of the function, only specifies positive- reals, not-negative reals. ie including $0$. Maybe strict mono-tonicity, and posi-tivity may help in this case. Notice, that given sub-additivity.

Answer (score 0):

See also:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity:,  which gives, Remember that these are sufficient conditions.

Notice that given sub-additivity:

\begin{align}
F\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\times (a+b) + \frac{b}{a+b} \times (a+b)\right)
& = F(a + b) \\
& \le F(a) + F(b) \\
& = F\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\times  (a+b)\right) + F\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\times  (a+b)\right),
\end{align}
where presumably $\frac{b}{a+b}$  $\in (0,1)$ if $a$,$b$ and $a+b$ are positive real numbers, as per the domain and range.

If, the function above is sub-additive over the positive reals.

$$F\left(\frac{a}{c} (c) + \frac{b}{c}(c)\right)
\le F\left(\frac{a}{c}(c)\right) + F\left(\frac{b}{c}(c)\right)$$
Where $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}=1, \land\, (\frac{b}{c},\frac{a}{c})\,\in [0,1]$